# JAVA SAML JKSKeyManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml

I hope someone can help me.
I am trying to create a sample application to test connection to ADFS

I was able to run the sample SAML code using SSOCircle.

Not i am trying to use it with the other ADFS server
I have been given a cert file ADFS.cer and a metadata.xml

I used the following command

```
keytool -import -alias myalias -file ADFS.cer -keystore myfile.jks -storepass mypass -noprompt
```

---

```
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
            .getResource("classpath:/saml/myfile.jks);
    String storePass = "mypass";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwords.put("apollo", "mypass");
    String defaultKey = "apollo";
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}
```

The file builds and when i run the file and hit the url http://localhost:8080/

java.lang.RuntimeException: Key for alias apollo not found

I have been reading few forums and read somewhere the Authenticated certs don't need password

I am not sure what i should be putting in place of defaultKey ("apollo")

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

While working on this further , this is what i have found. Following the following steps, i was able to resolve the keystore related exceptions

generates a key pair

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias mykey -keypass mypass  -keystore myJKSFile.jks
```

You can use the following command to list

```
keytool -v -list -keystore myJKSFile.jks
```

Add/import cert to the keystore file

```
keytool -importcert -alias differentAlias -file ADFS-CertFile.cer -keystore myJKSFile.jks
```

In the code (Spring configuration), use the following

```
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
            .getResource("classpath:/saml/myJKSFile.jks");
    String storePass = " mypass";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwords.put("mykey", " mypass");
    String defaultKey = "mykey";
   return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the other configuration, i got stuck in this configuration from long.
Also did you kept configuration as extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
  extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);